# What is zweibein for a hypersurface $f(\pmb{x})=0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, physics

For an *N*-dimensional hypersurface $f(\pmb{x})=0$ embedded in *N+1* flat dimensional space in which the coordinates  $x^1,x^2,\dots,x^{N+1}$ are *N+1* Cartesian ones, we can introduce $N$ local parameters $u^1,u^2,\dots,u^N$ such that $\pmb{x}=\pmb{x}(u^1,u^2,\dots,u^N)$. Then, a simple question is, what is zweibein for this hypersurface $f(\pmb{x})=0$? Please give some textbooks for references.

Question 1: The terminology zweibein may not be so commonly used in mathematics textbooks. In physics textbooks, the termiology dyad is also used instead.

Question 2: The zweibein may be referred to as the tetrad defined by $\pmb{e}^a_μ=∂\pmb{x}(u^1,u^2,\dots,u^N)/∂u^μ$
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism

Comment: Where did you find this "zweibein" terminology? I never seen it in math literature. The literal translation from German is "bipod", which does not make much sense in your setting.

Comment: The word  "zweibein" is commonly used in physics literature, for instance, M..A.H. Vozmediano, M.I. Katsnelson, F. Guinea, Gauge fields in graphene, Volume 496, Pages 109-150 (November 2010). The word "dyad" for two-dimensions, and "triad" for three- dimensions, and "D-ad" for D- dimensions, see,  H Kleinert，Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics, Statistics, Polymer Physics, (World Sci. 1995) P.31.

Comment: Then, perhaps, physics stackexchange is a better place for the question. Or, at least, add the tag [mathematical-physics]: This is not a differential geometry question since differential geometers do not use this terminology. If you want a formal answer to your question is that the zweibein is not well-defined in your setting since it depends on a choice of a (local) coordinates or local trivialization of the tangent bundle. It is like asking for coordinates of an object without specifying which coordinate system you are using.

Comment: The tag [mathematical-physics] is added. Thanks.

Comment: I think the correct term is "vielbein", zweibein is for a two dimensional vector basis as vierbein for a four dimensional vector basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most good books on general relativity and supergravity have reviews on tangent spaces and Vielbeine/Vierbeine, as these are needed to express fermions on the tangent spaces to a curved space. Consider [Weinberg's classic Gravity text](https://ftp.space.dtu.dk/pub/Henrik/Weinberg%20S.%20Gravitation%20and%20cosmology..%20principles%20and%20applications%20of%20the%20general%20theory%20of%20relativity%20%28Wiley,%201972%29%28ISBN%200471925675%29%28685s%29.pdf) Ch 12.5.

Here, I'll give you a simplest example of Zweibeine on a beach-ball, $S^2$ which might serve you when you learn the general theory.

The constraint is, of course, $f=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$, so $df/2=0=zdz+ydy+xdx$, hence 
$$
dz=-(x dx +y dy)/z,
$$
hence 
$$
dz^2=(xdx+ydy)^2/(1-x^2-y^2)=(xdx+ydy)^2/w, \qquad w\equiv 1-x^2-y^2 .
$$

Consequently,
$$
ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu \\
=dx^2+dy^2+(x^2 dx ^2 +2xydx dy +y^2dy)/w,
$$
so that 
$$
g_{\mu\nu}= \delta_{\mu\nu} +x^\mu x^\nu /w,
$$
and its inverse 
$$
g^{\mu\nu}= \delta_{\mu\nu} -x^\mu x^\nu ,
$$
$$
\det g_{\mu\nu}=1/w .
$$

The Zweibeine are basically the "square roots" of the metric,
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\delta_{ab} V_\mu^a V_\nu^b , \\
\delta^{ab}=g^{\mu\nu} V_\mu^a V_\nu^b , 
$$
$$
V_\mu^a=\delta_{\mu a} -\frac{x^\mu x^a}{1-w}\left (1+\frac{1}{\sqrt {w}}\right ) 
$$
$$V^{\mu a}=\delta_{\mu a} -\frac{x^\mu x^a}{1-w}(1+{\sqrt {w}}).
$$
The latter convert commuting gradients $\partial_\mu$ to non-commuting gradients on the tangent space, $V_a^\mu \partial_\mu$.
The positive square root of *w* may be equivalently supplanted by its negative square root, if desired.

Check them.

In matrix form,
$$
g_{\mu\nu}=   \begin{pmatrix}
      1+x^2/w&xy/w\\
      xy/w&1+y^2/w
    \end{pmatrix},
$$
$$
g^{\mu\nu}=   \begin{pmatrix}
      1-x^2&-xy\\
      -xy&1-y^2
    \end{pmatrix},
$$
and check the square root of the metric is 
$$
V_{\mu}^{a}=   \begin{pmatrix}
      1-x^2v&-xyv\\
      -xyv&1-y^2v
    \end{pmatrix},  \qquad v\equiv (1+1/\sqrt{w})/(1-w).
$$